# specify environment variables for conf file in windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, playframework-2.6

My `application.conf` uses environment variables like this

```
cassandraUri = ${?DB_CASSANDRA_URI}
```

I am starting my `Play` application using the `.bat` file created by `sbt dist`. I have specified the value of `DB_CASSANDRA_URI` both in the `.bat` file and also in `cmd`.

```
set "PSK"="mysecret"
set "ALLOWED_NODES"="localhost"
set "DB_CASSANDRA_URI"="localhost"
set "DB_CASSANDRA_PORT"="9042"
set "DB_KEYSPACE_NAME"="ksname"
set "DB_USERNAME"="cassandra"
set "DB_PASSWORD"="cassandra"
set "EMAIL_SERVER"=""
set "EMAIL_USER"=""
set "EMAIL_PASSWORD"=""
set "MOCK_EMAIL"="true"
```

But the application still can't read the variables.

Am I setting the variables incorrectly? What is the right way?

Comment: The correct syntax is `set VAR=Value` or `set "VAR=Value"` (the latter only works when Command Extensions are enabled, but this is the default anyway), you are using too many quotes, `set "VAR"="Value"` actually assigns the value `"Value` to the variable `VAR"` with Command Extensions enabled, or the value `"Value"` to the variable `VAR` otherwise…

Comment: You also cannot create an empty variable, which is technically referred to as undefined. That means `%"EMAIL_SERVER"%`, or `%EMAIL_SERVER%`, do not exist if they have no value, so for those examples, you could use, `set EMAIL_SERVER=`, or better, `set "EMAIL_SERVER="`, although it may be a little quicker for all of those three 'empty' examples to use, `For %%G In (SERVER USER PASSWORD)Do Set "EMAIL_%%G="`